# Integer solutions for $x^2-y^3 = 23$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

As the title stated, I am wondering the integers $x,y$ that satisfy the equation $x^2-y^3 = 23$.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a [Mordell equation (or curve)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordell_curve) and from this [table](http://tnt.math.se.tmu.ac.jp/simath/MORDELL/MORDELL+) (see E_+00023) no solution is known nor exists :

```
E_+00023: r = 0   t = 1   #III =  1
          E(Q) = {O}
          R =   1.0000000000
           0 integral points
```

(except the Tate-Shafarevic group #III the parameters correspond to the example 2 at the beginning of file i.e. there is no rational solution)

---

**PROOF**: Concerning the impossibility of integer solutions this was proved by Jonquières in 1878 and the (french) paper is available at [Numdam](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/NAM/NAM_1878_2_17_/NAM_1878_2_17__374_1/NAM_1878_2_17__374_1.pdf). Starting from III of page 376 we find (adapted to your specific case $k=23$) :

We search solutions of $\quad y^3+23=x^2$.
Let's set $\ c:=3\ $ then $\ k=23=c^3-4\ $

Let's suppose that an even $y$ is solution of $\ y^3+3^3-4=x^2\ $ then the left part will be of type $8n-1$ while the right part will be of kind $8n+1$ (since $x$ must be odd).

We infer that $y$ must be odd and $x$ even so let's set $x:=2t$ and rewrite our equation as $$y^3+c^3=4(t^2+1)$$

This may be factorized as :
$$(y+c)\underset{\text{odd}}{\underbrace{(y^2-cy+c^2)}}=4(t^2+1)$$

Since the second term must be odd ($o^2-o^2+o^2$) we deduce that the first one must be multiple of $4$. Since $\ c\equiv -1\bmod{4}\ $ we get $\ y=4n+1$.

The second factor $(y^2-3y+9)\equiv 1^2-(-1)1+1\equiv -1\bmod{4}\ $ i.e. it is of form $\ 4k-1$. But this factor should divide the $(t^2+1)$ factor at the right. I'll let you prove that this is not possible for a number of form $\ 4k-1$.